# Shapes of logits and labels are incompatible

Tags: python, tensorflow

The full error message is like this:

> ValueError: Shapes (2, 1) and (50, 1) are incompatible

It occurs when my model is trained. The mistake either is in my input_fn:

```
train_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
    x = {"x" : training_data},
    y = training_labels,
    batch_size = 50,
    num_epochs = None,
    shuffle = True)
```

in my logits and loss function:

```
dense = tf.layers.dense(inputs = pool2_flat, units = 1024, activation = tf.nn.relu)
dropout = tf.layers.dropout(inputs = dense, rate = 0.4, training = mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN)
logits = tf.layers.dense(inputs = dropout, units = 1)

loss = tf.losses.softmax_cross_entropy(labels = labels, logits = logits)
```

or in my dataset. I can only print out the shape of my dataset for you to take a look at it.

```
#shape of the dataset
train_data.shape
(1196,2,1)
train_data[0].shape
(2,1)

#this is the data
train_data[0][0].shape
(1,)
train_data[0][0][0].shape
(20,50,50)

#this is the labels
train_data[0][1].shape
(1,)
```

The problem seems to be the shape of the logits. They are supposed to be `[batch_size, num_classes]` in this case `[50,1]` but are `[2,1]`. The shape of the labels is correctly `[50,1]`

I have made a github gist if you want to take a look at the whole code.
https://gist.github.com/hjkhjk1999/38f358a53da84a94bf5a59f44050aad5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, you are stating that the inputs to your model will be feed in batches of 50 samples per batch with one variable. But it looks like your are feeding actually a batch of 2 samples with 1 variable (`shape=[2, 1]`) despite feeding labels with shape `[50, 1]`.

That's the problem, you are giving 50 'questions' and two 'answers'.

Also, your dataset is shaped in a really weird way. I see you named your github gist 3D Conv. If you are indeed trying to do a 3D convolution you might want to reshape your dataset into a tensor (numpy array) of this shape `shape = [samples, width, height, deepth]`

Comment: The input tensor has the shape `[-1, width, height, depth, 1]`. The numpy array is getting reshaped to this tensor before being fed to the network. So I don't see the error in the input.

Comment: FYI for ``tf.layers.conv3d`` with the default ``"data_format=channels_last"``, you're expected to pass shape ``(batch, depth, height, width, channels)``. Common gotcha with ``conv3d``. [Docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/layers/conv3d)

Comment: @SimonZeng ok if you trust your shape processing then check for the amount of samples for your input and for your labels, it looks like you are feeding an input tensor with 2 samples and 50 labels

Comment: The mistake was at the softmax layer where I had `tf.reshape(pool2, [-1,51200])`. This somehow changed the batch size to 2. I changed it to `[-1, 2048]`and it works perfectly now.